# Is there a crowdfunding site for Bitcoin?

Tags: crowdfunding

Does a crowdfunding site like [kickstarter.com](http://www.kickstarter.com/) exist, which accepts bitcoins instead of dollars?

Comment: Questions seeking product or service reviews are off-topic because they tend to attract subjective, low-quality, and spam answers.  However, I think that policy should be changed and rely more heavily on site visitors to downvote low quality answers.  The current answer to this question is outdated but was decent.  I don't know of a better place to look for an answer to this question, and if the policy made asking it okay, it might have a better and constantly improving answer.

Answer (score 20):

For donation-based crowdfunding:

- http://www.BitcoinStarter.com
- http://www.CoinFunder.com
- http://www.nestorbooster.com
- http://ignitiondeck.com/id/bitcoin-crowdfunding

There's also:

- http://www.Propster.me
- http://www.PirateMyFilm.com
- http://www.Booster.io

and some day coming back:

- http://www.BitcoinChipIn.com

Of course, the "equity" markets for equity-based crowdfunding:

- http://www.BitFunder.com
- http://www.MPEX.co
- http://www.CryptoStocks.com

And a forms of microlending from the crowd include:

- http://www.BTCJam.com

and others.

[Update: Thanks to others answering this question as well, I've updated this list with their input as well.]

Comment: Almost all of these sites are now defunct

Answer (score 5):

[Lighthouse](https://www.vinumeris.com/lighthouse) is an excellent decentralised crowdfunding app by Mike Hearn (one of the Bitcoin Core / bitcoinj devs).

Comment: check out https://www.reddit.com/r/LighthouseProjects/ for project to fund

Answer (score 2):

Another option, buy/issue shares or bonds: [Cryptostocks.com](https://cryptostocks.com)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bitcoinstarter.com hasn't launched yet, but it does have a webpage where you can submit your email address to be notified when it does launch.

Comment: Hi jjwatts! When possible please include more information than just a link. In this case the fact that the site hasn't launched yet should definitely be included in the answer.

Comment: The url is dead

Answer (score 0):

nestorbooster is a crowdfunding site for board games. They accept Bitcoin payments.

http://www.nestorbooster.com

Answer (score 0):

BTC Jam  www.btcjam.com

They do quite a bit to verify the users, including using the Web of trust set up for bitcoin-otc.

Comment: They are shutting down. Don't accept any new users.

Answer (score 0):

I built https://fundhub.org/ for crowdfunding software, no fees :)

Comment: I think it's dead now

Answer (score 0):

We received a lot of requests for this, so we built a Bitcoin extension for IgnitionDeck: http://ignitiondeck.com/id/bitcoin-crowdfunding/

This way, you can use Bitcoin to crowdfund on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

The free open-source [BTCPay Server](https://btcpayserver.org/) allows [creating crowdfunding apps](https://docs.btcpayserver.org/Apps/#crowdfunding-app).